# Why is docker failing to mount a volume and start on CentOS 7?

Tags: mysql, docker, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 minimal install with networking enabled and a few extra simple tools installed (e.g. htop). Docker was installed as per these [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/).

The command that I am running is this:

```
docker run --name mysql5.6 -v /tmp/mysql:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=blah  -p 22 -p 3306 -d mysql:5.6
```

But the container will not start. If I run it like this, things work:

```
docker run --name mysql5.6  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=blah  -p 22 -p 3306 -d mysql:5.6
```

As per the instructions [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), I ran the command

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /tmp/mysql
```

The above is running on a VM.

I tried what I believe to be the same configuration on a desktop system and things worked if I edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` to look like this:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=minimum
```

Please note the `SELINUX=disabled` and `SELINUXTYPE=minimum settings`. For some reason, that did not work on the VM either.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
This is definitely a permissions problem. The system that "worked" had an older version of docker. The daemon was started like this:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon --selinux-enabled
```

The newer version started like this:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
```

So I added the `--selinux-enabled` option to the newer docker and it made no observable difference in behavior. The only way to get things to work is to make files writeable by other (666).

So, I can make it work by opening up the file all the way. Is that the expected behavior? It does not seem right. Why does the file need to be writeable?

Comment: Multiple possibilities: A) `/etc/mysql/conf.d` is a directory. MySQL is expecting a `my.cnf` file or pointer to that. B) No sufficient rights on /tmp/mysql on the host system. C) Nothing in /tmp/mysql. D) Other errors: Login interactive and check the mysql log files for that.

Comment: Thank you Norbert. The problem is that there are no log files to look at. The Docker container never started. Note that this very same process works on other systems. Here is what /tmp/mysql has in it:
> find /tmp/mysql 
/tmp/mysql
/tmp/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: The `/tmp/mysql`: Ok. What does the image `/etc/my.cnf` contain?
What does `docker ps -a` tell you? If the container is listed there, it did start (and stop again in your case).

Comment: Argh! so sorry. You were right Norbert. My mask was screwed up on this new VM. The /tmp/mysql/ and the my.cnf in it were not open enough. As soon as I opened that up, it all works. This was a bone-headed mistake on my part. Thanks for mentioning the B) option above. If you want to supply a proper answer, I would be glad to give you credit for it.